# for loop in GNU Parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I am trying to download a large number of files from a webpage (which contains only a image, so I can use a simple wget), but want to speed it up using GNU Parallel. Can anyone please help me parallelize this for loop? Thanks.

```
    for i in `seq 1 1000`
    do
    wget -O "$i.jpg" www.somewebsite.com/webpage
    done
```

Comment: Append a whitespace and `&` at the end of your wget command.

Comment: A C-style for loop is better than using `seq` in `bash`: `for ((i=1; i<=1000; i++))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
 seq 1 1000 | parallel wget www.somewebsite.com/webpage/{}.jpg
```

You can also use the `-P` option to specify the number of jobs you want to run concurrently.

Also you may decide to use curl instead like:

```
parallel -P 1000 curl -o {}.jpg www.somewebsite.com/webpage/{}.jpg ::: {1..1000}
```

Comment: There's no reason to bring `curl` into the answer.

Comment: Is there a reason for that last bit, what's with the `::: {1..10000}`?